# What are good synonyms for "not yet connected"?

Tags: usability, interface, terminology

I'm working on a browser-based tool that allows users to interact with other users they are matched with. Relationships between users progress in a linear fashion along a series of states, initiated when a user requests to be connected with another user.

In the interface of the tool, a user can view all of the users they're matched with, regardless of the state of their relationship.

I'd like to allow users to navigate to a filtered version of this view that shows only users they have not yet requested a connection with, but I'm having trouble with what to call it.

"Unconnected Matches" isn't quite right. "Unconnected" carries unwanted connotations of having once been connected in the past.

Any good alternatives?

Comment: I recommend asking this over on english.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could list the states, and pick the least advanced relationship, and call it that.  Or you could say "unrelated".

Comment: @JohnDeters Do you feel this is off-topic for ux.stackexchange.com? Or do you think I'll get better answers from english?

Comment: I think you'll get better answers.  They have lots of "synonym-wanted" questions, and love to answer them.  You might even get some left-field suggestions that convey exactly the meaning you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**When you can't think of a noun for an anchor or headline, think of a verb**

If you can't quite think of a name for the content on the linked page, you can instead try thinking of the action that users would do there, just as the "registration page" may say "Register" or "Join."

In this case, something like "Make connections" or "Expand your network"?

Marketers would call this a *call to action*, and I think this is a case where  good marketing is also good UX.

Comment: Thanks for the out-of-box suggestion. I think this will solve the problem better than an adjective-noun combo.

Answer (score 5):

Why not go with something more positive such as **Available**. That way it wont have any unwanted connotations and users may be more interested in requesting a connection.

Comment: They're already a match if they're visible, so "potential match" isn't appropriate, but I like where you're going with "available"—thanks!

Comment: Ah missed that part in the original post, edited out.

Answer (score 0):

No Connection Established, Not linked yet, Not matched, Still Looking, Available